# Command to print the output in a row format

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to print the below output in a row format to a csv file. Can someone help me using awk or bash ?

```
Server abc.com
osbits x64
ostype windows
```

I want to print the output like this and forward to a csv format

```
abc.com x64 windows
```

Comment: Care to accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

With awk you want to set the Output Field Separator (OFS) to Comma, and then print the 2nd, 4th, and 6th fields to match your example.

For multi-line input you can use sed to join the lines prior to awk

```
me@myvm:~ $ cat servers.txt 
Server abc.com
osbits x64
ostype windows
me@myvm:~ $ cat servers.txt | sed -e 'N;N;s/\n/ /g' 
Server abc.com osbits x64 ostype windows
me@myvm:~ $ cat servers.txt | sed -e 'N;N;s/\n/ /g' | awk '{ OFS=","; print $2,$4,$6}'
abc.com,x64,windows
```

Comment: It was when my response was posted :)

Answer (score 0):

This works but I'm sure there's a more idiomatic way to do it:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", ((NR==1)?"":", "),$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the input

```
Server abc.com foo.com bar.com buz.org
osbits x64 x86 sparc ppc
ostype windows linux solaris mac
```

the awk script

```
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)
        a[i][NR] = $i;
}
END {
    for (i=2;i<=length(a); ++i) {
        str = a[i][1]
        for (j=2; j<=length(a[i]); ++j)
            str = str "," a[i][j]
        print str
    }
}
```

produces

```
abc.com,x64,windows
foo.com,x86,linux
bar.com,sparc,solaris
buz.org,ppc,mac
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input file, `file.txt`, looks like this:

```
Server abc.com
osbits x64
ostype windows
```

All of the following solutions will produce this output:

```
Server,abc.comosbits,x64ostype,windows
```

1. awk

   ```
   awk '{printf "%s,%s",$1,$2}END{print ""}' file.txt
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -000ane 'print join ",",@F,"\n"' file.txt
   ```
3. shell

   ```
     while read a b ; do printf "%s,%s" "$a" "$b"; done < file.txt; echo
   ```