# awk OFS not producing expected value

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file

```
[root@nmk~]# cat file
abc>
sssd>
were>
```

I run both these variations of the awk commands

```
[root@nmk~]# cat file | awk -F\>  ' { print $1}' OFS=','
abc
sssd
were

[root@nmk~]# cat file | awk -F\>  ' BEGIN { OFS=","}  { print $1}' 
abc
sssd
were
[root@nmk~]#
```

But my expected output is

```
abc,sssd,were
```

What's missing in my commands ?

Comment: Using ORS gets me what I was looking for.


    [root@nmk~]# cat file | awk -F\>  ' BEGIN { ORS=","}  { print $1}' 
    abc,sssd,were,[root@nmk~]

Comment: But it adds a comma at the last.

Comment: Related (possibly even duplicate, sort-of): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241808/awk-command-to-print-the-output-in-a-row-format

Comment: `OFS` is only inserted between the arguments of a single call to `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line of input in awk is a *record*, so what you want to set is the Output *Record* Separator, `ORS`.  The `OFS` variable holds the Output *Field* Separator, which is used to separate different parts of each line.

Since you are setting the *input* field separator, `FS`, to `>`, and `OFS` to `,`, an easy way to see how these work is to add something on each line of your file after the `>`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=">"; OFS=","} {$1=$1} 1' <<<$'abc>def\nsssd>dsss\nwere>wolf'
abc,def
sssd,dsss
were,wolf
```

So you want to set the ORS.  The default record separator is newline, so whatever you set ORS to effectively replaces the newlines in the input.  But that means that if the last line of input has a newline - which is usually the a case - that last line will also get a copy of your new ORS:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=">"; ORS=","}  1' <<<$'abc>def\nsssd>dsss\nwere>wolf'
abc>def,sssd>dsss,were>wolf,
```

It also won't get a newline at all, because that newline was interpreted as an input record separator and turned into the output record separator - it became the final comma.

So you have to be a little more explicit about what you're trying to do:

```
  awk 'BEGIN { FS=">"          } # split input on >
      (NR>1) { printf ","      } # if not the first line, print a ,
             { printf "%s", $1 } # print the first field (everything up to the first >) 
         END { printf "\n"     } # add a newline at the end
      ' <<<$'abc>\nsssd>\nwere>'
```

Which outputs this:

```
abc,sssd,were
```

Comment: Thanks, @EdMorton - went with `printf "\n"` for consistency.

Answer (score 6):

You're just a bit confused about the meaning/use of FS, OFS, RS and ORS. Take another look at the man page. I think this is what you were trying to do:

```
$ awk -F'>' -v ORS=',' '{print $1}' file
abc,sssd,were,$
```

but this is probably closer to the output you really want:

```
$ awk -F'>' '{rec = rec (NR>1?",":"") $1} END{print rec}' file
abc,sssd,were
```

or if you don't want to buffer the whole output as a string:

```
$ awk -F'>' '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1?",":""), $1} END{print ""}' file
abc,sssd,were
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F\> -v ORS=""  'NR>1{print ","$1;next}{print $1}' file
```

to print newline at the end:

```
awk -F\> -v ORS=""  'NR>1{print ","$1;next}{print $1} END{print "\n"}' file
```

output:

```
abc,sssd,were
```

Comment: Why it fails to print a newline at the last?

Comment: @Avinash Raj, because output record separator (ORS) is set to "". I have edited to print the newline.

Comment: You should mention that that solution is gawk-specific, or put a space between `-v` and `ORS` so it's not.

Comment: @Ed Morton, thanks I have edited, But I tried the previous form (no space between `-v` and `ORS`) with `--posix` command line option, same output, no errors.

Comment: AFAIK POSIX doesn't specify whether or not a space is required between `-v` and the variable name (there's just conventions at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02 suggesting a space between -v and the var would be nice) so then it's up to each awk to do what they like with that and they're all still POSIX compliant. If you don't have a space, though, then it'll fail on nawk, xpg4 awk and others.

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/>\n/,/g;s/>$//' file
abc,sssd,were
```

Through Perl,

```
$ perl -00pe 's/>\n(?=.)/,/g;s/>$//' file
abc,sssd,were
```